# Riemann sums, asterisk meaning

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

What exactly does the * on the x sub i in the Riemann sum formula mean? The lesson I just did didn't even say and based on the example problem shown I wasn't able to tell for sure.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: The *in this http://formulasheet.com/images/eqn/search/607.png

Comment: You need to pick one of the three options and then substitute for $x_i^*$.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. I see it now. I didn't originally have that image to go off of, I found it quickly to show what I was talking about, but yea, ok between you and that image.. Got it.

Comment: Cool! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous; let $a =: x_{0} < x_{1} < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_{n} := b$; let $x_{i}^{*} \in [x_{i}, x_{i+1}]$ for each $0 \leq i \leq n-1$; then
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_{i}^{*})(x_{i+1} - x_{i})$ is called a Riemann sum.
In fact, usually $x_{i}^{*}$ just means an arbitrary point of a subinterval of a partition in the Riemann integration context.
But, of course, no need to stick to the *, you can use other symbols provided that you be consistent throughout.